# SQL Lock default

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions

I have created the following TSQL:

```
begin transaction
    update person.Address set addressline2 = 'The Town' where addressid=1 
    WAITFOR DELAY '0:00:010'
    commit
```

During the ten second delay you are not able to run this SQL statement in another SQL Studio Manager:

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Address
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Address where addressid=1
```

But you are able to run this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Address where addressid<>1
```

Does SQL Studio Manager choose the lock type? I don't believe it does as you can do this:

> SELECT * FROM Person.Address where addressid=1 nolock

I have read this webpage: > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx, but I am still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint NoLock also means 'Read Uncommitted' is applicable to select statements only. So, it will allow you to query the uncommitted data as well. Please find documentation  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx), where as the without hint, engine will not allow you to read uncommitted data.

Comment: Can you confirm that SQL Server chooses the type of lock for your query? +1.

Comment: I don't think I understood your query

Comment: Thanks.  Are you able to choose what lock you want to use or does SQL Server do it for you?

Comment: You probably, didn't understood the concept of Hints. Hints are meant to override the default configuration. SQL Server will try to allow DML statements according to the state of the data. In the current scenarion, if it's ok to read the uncommitted reads then you can go with NOLOCK option, but SQL Server does row/page/table level locking which is preventing you from reading the data. Like the same way, there are other hints which helps you to override the default configuration if one knows what he is doing.Choosing which lock to use depends completely on one's scenario.

Comment: Thanks.  If you get chance to look at my other transaction question then please do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874968/ado-net-isolation-level-v-transactionscope-isolation-level