# ADO.NET Isolation Level v TransactionScope isolation level

Tags: .net, transactions

I have read that the default isolation level for ADO.NET (when transactions aren't used i.e. each statement is executed as an atomic operation) is 'READ COMMITTED' and the default isolation level for TransactionScope (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) is 'SERIALIZABLE'.  Is there a reason for this?

I have read many webpages on this subject, but I have not yet found an answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

A **Transaction** is a unit of work, which basically means there are several activities are performed with in the scope. For example, **Booking a Cart** involves checking the product, checking the on-hand quantity, calculating shipping costs and updating the financial accounts. All of these actions should go as one or none, if any of them had a phantom reads like in case of Isolation level **'READ COMMITTED'** then it puts data in a stale state. If **'SERIALIZED'** scope is used then it will prevent any updates to the entities involved while in transaction.

In a case, where you are looking at Financial reports for a month, then **'READ COMMITTED'** Isolation level works, because you are looking at existing data and not making too many modifications, even phantom reads wouldn't create much difference in the reports.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe this answers my question.  I understand the difference between the two isolation types in question.  I am wandering why TransactionScope has a different isolation level by default in comparison to SQL Server.

Comment: Well, any RDBMS solutions by default they support ACID properties. By default, without transaction scope it will be READ COMMITTED. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason the isolation level is serializable with transactionscope? I suspect it is just a design decixision made by the transactionscope developer.

Comment: Think about this, any design is based on use case which you are probably aware. With in a single transaction, if you need control then it is READ COMMITTED for a single table would work, but what if you need support of updating multiple tables and making sure it satisfies ACID properties. Then you would need TransactionScope.Just another name for the Isolation level to differentiate, as you cannot do everything with in same isolation level.

Comment: Thanks again. Are you saying that you should always use a serializable isolation level if you are updating multiple tables?

Comment: If you're working with enterprise or complex transactions, then I would recommend Serializable, but the bottom line: One should be able to decide if the updates in multiple tables does require ACID properties for an application, then yes otherwise not required.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that a Transaction scope can span multiple (sub)transactions that all are coordinated with a distributed transaction coordinator (MS-DTC).  Most of the times you'll want to be sure that all subtransctions are working with the same data, even if a commit happened between them.

For example a service that has 3 methods: checkbalance, increasebalance & decreasebalance.
Each method starts a transaction, opens a database connections, executes a SQL, closes the connection and commits the transaction.

A typical scenario would then be for a client of this service to:

1. start master transaction
2. check balance of account 1
3. decrease balance of account 1
4. increase balance of account 2
5. commit master transaction

IsolationLevel.Serializable will make sure that all service calls will a) start from the same data and b) no one else is allowed to alter that data while the master transaction is running.

IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted can cause the balance of account 1 to go below zero if someone else decreased the balance with a sufficient amount and committed that transaction between the check and the decrease.